# How to access JSON Object value?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am returning a json as shown below

o/p of console.log(obj.roles);

```
[Object, Object, suggest: function, vanquish: function]
0: Object
        jnl_id: "2"
        jnl_journal_name: "About Origin of speci"
        role_id: "5"
        role_name: "Technical Head"
        usr_id: "7"
        usr_username: "dd"
        usrj_jnl_id: "2"
        usrj_usr_id: "7"
        __proto__: Object
1: Object
        jnl_id: "2"
        jnl_journal_name: "About Origin of speci"
        role_id: "10"
        role_name: "EBM - Reviewer"
        usr_id: "7"
        usr_username: "dd"
        usrj_jnl_id: "2"
        usrj_usr_id: "7"
        __proto__: Object
        length: 2
        __proto__: Array[0]
```

The ajax function is `datatype : json`

```
success:function (data) {                   
    obj = $.parseJSON(data);

    if(obj.status == "success"){
        console.log(obj.roles);

        $.each(obj.roles, function (index, value) {

            console.log(value.roles_id);//output undefined
            $("#journal_user_role").append($("<option>", {
                value: value.roles_id,
                text: value.roles
            }));
            $("#journal_user_role").trigger("chosen:updated");
        });
    }
}
```

I want to find the `role_id` and `role_name` and append on a multi select box.

Comment: dont parse it anymore if it is of `type json` can you show what is `console.log(data)`

Comment: @guradio  when i check the value of 'data' beforse parse,  {"status":"success","roles":[{"role_name":"Technical Head","role_id":"5","usr_username":"aa","jnl_journal_name":"About Origin of speci","usrj_usr_id":"1","usrj_jnl_id":"2","usr_id":"1","jnl_id":"2"},{"role_name":"EBM - Reviewer","role_id":"10","usr_username":"aa","jnl_journal_name":"About Origin of speci","usrj_usr_id":"1","usrj_jnl_id":"2","usr_id":"1","jnl_id":"2"}]} ,but i can't find the --->"data.status"  and "data.roles" value.

Comment: if you set dataType :'json' it will automatically parse your result are you getting the data you are expecting?i think something is missing from your value of data above comment ^

Comment: @guradio  console.log(data) => {"status":"success","roles":[{"role_name":"Technical Head","role_id":"5","usr_username":"dd","jnl_journal_name":"About Origin of speci","usrj_usr_id":"7","usrj_jnl_id":"2","usr_id":"7","jnl_id":"2"},{"role_name":"EBM - Reviewer","role_id":"10","usr_username":"dd","jnl_journal_name":"About Origin of speci","usrj_usr_id":"7","usrj_jnl_id":"2","usr_id":"7","jnl_id":"2"}]}

Comment: {
 `"status"`: "success",
 "roles": [{
  "role_name": "Technical Head",
  "role_id": "5",
  "usr_username": "dd",
  "jnl_journal_name": "About Origin of speci",
  "usrj_usr_id": "7",
  "usrj_jnl_id": "2",
  "usr_id": "7",
  "jnl_id": "2"
 }, {
  "role_nam‌​e": "EBM - Reviewer",
  "role_id": "10",
  "usr_username": "dd",
  "jnl_journal_name": "About Origin of speci",
  "usrj_usr_id": "7",
  "usrj_jnl_id": "2",
  "usr_id": "7",
  "jnl_id": "2"
 }]
} i can see status.. you just have to loop through them

Comment: 1 problem I see is that you have role_id but you're binding to roles_id and also role_name but you're using roles

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {
 "status": "success",
 "roles": [{
  "role_name": "Technical Head",
  "role_id": "5",
  "usr_username": "dd",
  "jnl_journal_name": "About Origin of speci",
  "usrj_usr_id": "7",
  "usrj_jnl_id": "2",
  "usr_id": "7",
  "jnl_id": "2"
 }, {
  "role_name": "EBM - Reviewer",
  "role_id": "10",
  "usr_username": "dd",
  "jnl_journal_name": "About Origin of speci",
  "usrj_usr_id": "7",
  "usrj_jnl_id": "2",
  "usr_id": "7",
  "jnl_id": "2"
 }]
};
var dataroles = data.roles;
console.log("status: " + data.status);
for(var i = 0 ; i < dataroles.length; i++){
  
  console.log("role_id "+ i +": "+ dataroles[i].role_id);
  console.log("role_name "+ i +": "+ dataroles[i].role_name);
  }
```

Try this one

Comment: console.log(data.status) and (data.roles ) are undefined

Comment: that's why i tried to parse the data,obj = $.parseJSON(data);...then i tried console.log(obj.status),i got "success"...

Comment: check again i showed the status while roles is another object you need to loop through them you can check the value of role id and role name i showed them

Comment: when i tried this, console value is                                                             "status: success settings:934
role_id 0: 5 settings:938
role_name 0: Technical Head settings:939
role_id 1: 10 settings:938
role_name 1: undefined ",second one is undefined

Comment: I faced one more problem,without declare the data directly,i can't get the o/p.   success:function (data)
    {
// if i declare the variable var data = ..... then i got the o/p,but the console.log(data) is same as var data...//    
var dataroles = data.roles;
console.log("status: " + data.status);
for(var i = 0 ; i < dataroles.length; i++){
  
  console.log("role_id "+ i +": "+ dataroles[i].role_id);
  console.log("role_name "+ i +": "+ dataroles[i].role_name);
  }

Comment: you dont need to declare it because the `data` in success function will be equal to that `data`

Comment: yes i know,but i tried like this   success:function (data)
    {
     

var dataroles = data.roles;
console.log(dataroles);
console.log("status: " + data.status);
for(var i = 0 ; i < dataroles.length; i++){
  
  console.log("role_id "+ i +": "+ dataroles[i].role_id);
  console.log("role_name "+ i +": "+ dataroles[i].role_name);
  },but then the data.roles and data.status are undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **value['roles_id']** instead of **value.roles_id** .....